# How to customize response from @query in springboot API

Tags: java, mysql, json, api, spring-boot

I have a problem with my API @query reponse in SpringBoot.

First I will show u my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/osoba")
public class APIController {

@Autowired
private KsiazkaRepo ksiazkaRepo;

@JsonView(OnlyName.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getAll")
public Ksiazka find(@RequestParam("id") int id){
    String autor = ksiazkaRepo.findInfoById(id);
    Ksiazka ksiazka = new Ksiazka();
    ksiazka.setAutor(autor);
    return ksiazka;
}
```

---

```
**@Repository
public interface KsiazkaRepo extends JpaRepository<Ksiazka, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT ksiazka.tytul, ksiazka.autor FROM IEci8d0gZc.ksiazka WHERE ksiazka.id_ksiazka = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    String findInfoById(@Param("id") int id);

}**
```

---

```
@Entity
@Validated
public class Ksiazka {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idKsiazka;
private int idKategoria;
private String isbn;
@JsonView(OnlyName.class)
private String tytul;
@JsonView(OnlyName.class)
private String autor;
private int stron;
private String wydawnictwo;
private int rokWydania;
private String opis;


public Ksiazka(){ }

public Ksiazka(int idKsiazka, int idKategoria, String isbn, String tytul, String autor, int stron, String wydawnictwo, int rokWydania, String opis) {
    this.idKsiazka = idKsiazka;
    this.idKategoria = idKategoria;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.tytul = tytul;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.stron = stron;
    this.wydawnictwo = wydawnictwo;
    this.rokWydania = rokWydania;
    this.opis = opis;
}

public int getIdKsiazka() {
    return idKsiazka;
}

public void setIdKsiazka(int idKsiazka) {
    this.idKsiazka = idKsiazka;
}

public int getIdKategoria() {
    return idKategoria;
}

public void setIdKategoria(int idKategoria) {
    this.idKategoria = idKategoria;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public String getTytul() {
    return tytul;
}

public void setTytul(String tytul) {
    this.tytul = tytul;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public int getStron() {
    return stron;
}

public void setStron(int stron) {
    this.stron = stron;
}

public String getWydawnictwo() {
    return wydawnictwo;
}

public void setWydawnictwo(String wydawnictwo) {
    this.wydawnictwo = wydawnictwo;
}

public int getRokWydania() {
    return rokWydania;
}

public void setRokWydania(int rokWydania) {
    this.rokWydania = rokWydania;
}

public String getOpis() {
    return opis;
}

public void setOpis(String opis) {
    this.opis = opis;
}
```

---

And my interface OnlyName is empty.
When I'm using it like that like it is right not I can get simple response

Like:

```
{
    "tytul": null,
    "autor": "Mistrz czystego kodu. Kodeks postępowania profesjonalnych programistów,Robert C. Martin"
}
```

I understand that my response from @query is in String and that's why I'm getting only one result, but How should I change to get all String or something like that? Maybe String[]?

I can also create 2 different custom asking @query and get from them

```
1. imie,
2. nazwisko,
```

but this should not be the case.

Many thanks for help,
Ciao

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the steps here**

In here,  I am trying to tell you how to do this simply

1. Change the query , It should return list

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT ksiazka.tytul, ksiazka.autor FROM IEci8d0gZc.ksiazka WHERE ksiazka.id_ksiazka = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findInfoById(@Param("id") int id); // here you can return result as list
```

2. Change the return type in  "public Ksiazka find" as list

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/osoba")
public class APIController {

@Autowired
private KsiazkaRepo ksiazkaRepo;

@JsonView(OnlyName.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getAll")
    public List<Ksiazka> find(@RequestParam("id") int id){
}
```

3. Inside body try to do get result as list ,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/osoba")
public class APIController {

@Autowired
private KsiazkaRepo ksiazkaRepo;

@JsonView(OnlyName.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getAll")
    public List<Ksiazka> find(@RequestParam("id") int id){
     List<String> autor = ksiazkaRepo.findInfoById(id); // get result as as  list
     List<Ksiazka> ksiazkaList = new ArrayList<>(); // create list from Ksiazka 
     for (String autors : autor) { // returned result you can loop 
    Ksiazka ksiazka = new Ksiazka(); // create Object to Ksiazka

    ksiazka.setAutor(autors);
    ksiazkaList.add(ksiazka); //add created object to List
        }
       return ksiazkaList; // return your list

       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dulaj. I have still few errors in your code. First of all compilator dont know what means "args". It should be List of string from query result ? And I cannot put "ksiazka.setAutor(autor);" cause Autor in my Class is as a String not List<String>. I can use String.valueOf but it still doesnt work

Comment: ,Have you run it , is it okay now

Comment: Still this same. Resut: 
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Mistrz czystego kodu. Kodeks postępowania profesjonalnych programistów,Robert C. Martin"

Comment: Now you can see , code is running and it will return list , Now just check your DB Because of when you pass the ID , It should not be related to one row , it  should be related to comment then it will return all

Comment: Check first post. I added screen from db how it looks like

Comment: thanks for updating question , now it is very clear

Comment: Actually ,In query , you are searching from ksiazka.id_ksiazka , then , it is for one person unique , then it will return one record only

Comment: If you are trying to searchin it from id_kategoria and pass ID of  id_kategoria, If will return ,related records

Comment: Sooo... I if wanna get ksiazka.tytul and ksiazka.autor  I should create 2 diference query ? If I'm searching by id_ksiazka which is unique?

Comment: ksiazka.id_ksiazka Id is unique , as i thing , it is primary key , when you are trying find record from primary key , it will return one record , actually my code is not wrong

Comment: So easiest way to get tytul and autor if I wanna find it by id_ksiazka is making 2 difference @query ?

Comment: actually you can fetch   ksiazka.tytul and ksiazka.autor   when you are searching from  id_ksiazka , it will return one record according to your parsing ID,

Comment: No you don't need to do two queries

Comment: I already have added query and , you don't need to create two query to get data related to one unique iD

Comment: could you please run my code and share md response here

Comment: I did. I have both in 1 line. Tytul and Autor